# Get force.com site URL in Custom Formula Fields

Tags: formula, force.com-sites, force

Trying to populate the Site URL in Custom Field. **Eg:** siteUrl/ RecordId

For this, I created  New Custom setting and added the value in that filed and accessing the URL as below.

`$Setup.Center_Profile__c.URL__c/Id`

It's Working as expected.

Is there any way we can get the Site name directly in  formula filed without adding in Custom Settings. Please help me on this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_site.htm

Gone through this link and tried `$Site.Domain` in formula field , no luck. Please guide me on this.
Thanks